# QLabel Anywhere wordwrap or char-wrap?

Tags: qt, qt4

word wrap mode in qlabel works only with white-spaces but if a single word is long enough then it got clipped.
To overcome this we can use QTextEdit which gives functionality of wordwrap anywhere, But there is no vertical alignment available in QTextEdit.
So is there any third good option or any way I can use anywhere ( fixed size) word wrapping in QLabel or vertical alignment in QTextEdit?

Or finally I have to manually break the word in qlabel.

Answer (score -3):

Read the documentation. `QLabel::setWordWrap( bool )` is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: `QLabel::setWordWrap()` only wraps at word boundaries, not at arbitrary character positions.